# Django session key based expiration

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I'm using Django sessions and I want to set expiry for a particular key. In an AJAX view I'm doing the following

```
request.session['a'] = True
request.session.set_expiry(604800)
```

Does this set the expiry for that particular key or that session? I'm setting the sessions for other keys in other AJAX views in a similar way.

If I print `request.session.get_expiry_date()` in my view I get the date 7 days from now regardless of when I set the expiry. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `set_expiry` is a method of the `session` it sets the expiry of the session.

The Django session is a whole object, it is not possible (without manual work) to set the expiry for a specific key)

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit on the manual work that can be done for this? Basically I have a various lists on which visitors can vote once every week. Django sessions seems the way to go since I don't have a User model.

Comment: @YinYang you could use [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#basic-usage) for this, maybe?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Where the cache key could be the session key?

Comment: @YinYang not sure I understand you. I meant when a visitor votes you set a cache key for that visitor with expiry time set to 7 days. The next time visitor tries to vote you check if the cache key for them is set. If not, then it's expired and visitor can vote.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff I do not have a User or Visitor model. How can I set the cache key for that visitor?

Comment: Just set the cache key to the session id and follow Anton's suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you `set_expiry` as an integer the expiry age is defined as seconds of inactivity.

When you call the `get_expiry_age` method, a modification parameter defaults to now and the "seconds of inactivity" starts counting from zero.

If you do not want the counter to reset each time you call the `get_expiry_age`, you should specify a `timedelta` upon setting expiry:

```
from datetime import timedelta

request.session.set_expiry(timedelta(seconds=604800))
```

See [what does get_expiry_age() return in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702122/what-does-get-expiry-age-return-in-django)