# what does get_expiry_age() return in Django

Tags: django

Instead of returning actual seconds left for expiry, `request.session.get_expiry_age()` returns fixed value=10 set in  `request.session.set_expiry(10).`

In homepage view:

```
request.session['var1']=1
request.session.set_expiry(10)
```

In view2:

```
print(request.session['var1'])
```

No matter how many times I refresh view2, I get keyError `key not found` 10 seconds from the moment last time homepage view was called.

That means session does expire after 10 seconds from when homepage view was called.

Is there any other inbuilt function that can show actual seconds left for session expiry each time view2 was called.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a subtle distinction in the semantics of session expiration that can be gleaned from the documentation of [`set_expiry()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry):

> Sets the expiration time for the session. You can pass a number of different values:
>
> - If `value` is an integer, the session will expire after that many ***seconds of inactivity***.
> - If `value` is a `datetime` or `timedelta` object, the session will expire at that ***specific date/time***.

In other words, when you say `set_expiry(10)`, you're not saying that the session should expire 10 seconds from now, you're saying that the session should expire after 10 seconds of inactivity.

And since [`get_expiry_age()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age) has a `modification` parameter that defaults to now, it will always return `10`.

If you want the session to expire 10 seconds from now, you need to set a specific `datetime` or `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

request.session.set_expiry(timedelta(seconds=10))
```

If you do that, `get_expiry_age()` should work as you expect.

Comment: I set set_expiry(10) in homepage, then i go to view2. No matter how many times I refresh view2 or go to any view other then homepage - the session will expire 10 seconds from the time I last rendered homepage view. 
What I would like to do is be able to get exact number of seconds left when I call view2. 
First time i call view2 it may say 9 seconds left. second time i call view2 it may say 3 seconds left for expiry. 
Is there a way to do that

Comment: @Aseem: Do you understand my point, though, that `set_expiry(10)` isn't setting an *absolute* expiration time, it's setting a *relative* expiration time? Therefore, there's no way of knowing "the exact number of seconds left" because that could change at any time.

Comment: @Aseem: In more practical terms, a relative expiration time is implemented by setting an expire time on the session cookie, and expiration is controlled by the browser. That information is not available on the server. Setting an absolute expiration time is controlled by the server, and that value is available in the API.